# Disabling a button doesn't fire click event on server side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an imagebutton in my aspx page like:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnProcessPayment" ImageUrl="~/Images/process-payment.png" OnClientClick="return disableButton(this);"
                                    runat="server" OnClick="btnProcessPayment_Click" />
```

This is my javascript function:

```
function disableButton(button) {
            button.disabled = true;
            return true;
        }
```

As you can see in my javascript event handler I have disabled the button to prevent the user from click the button twice. However, even my server side event handler doesn't get fired due to this. What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** If I comment out this line     `button.disabled = true;` all works out pretty well.

Comment: I just noticed the same issue. At least I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling the button disables the form submit as well. You need to do the submit yourself:

```
function disableButton(button) { 
    button.disabled = true; 
    __doPostBack(<%= btnProcessPayment.ClientID %>,'');   // need to manually submit
    return true; 
}
```

Updated as per [Waqas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455814/waqas) suggestion!

Comment: This doesn't work. The event handler still doesn't execute. Finally I got it working using Vinay's approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344408/disable-submit-button-in-case-of-multiple-click-c Although it looks bit of hack setting timeout and then disabling but it works.

Comment: `button.id` - check if this is correct. Otherwise, try doing a `document.form1.submit()` (change it as per your code).

Comment: replace button.id with <%=btnProcessPayment.ClientID%>

Comment: @Brad8118: do not assume jQuery! or prototype. What does `$` stand for anyway? :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to fire out serverside event of the button some thing like this

```
onclick="this.disabled=true;__doPostBack('buttonclientid','');"
```

or

```
 function disableButton(button) {
            button.disabled = true;
            __doPostBack('buttonclientid','');
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this and it worked for me

```
 __doPostBack('<%= btnSubmit.ClientID %>', '');
```

where `btnSubmit` is the ID of my button and I wanted to trigger the server side click event for the button. It works.