# Disabling a button prevents click event to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, mouseclick-event

I have a repeater with a button in that saves some data to the DB. My issue is sometime the call down to the DB takes a little bit and the user sometimes will click save a few times causing multiple entries to be added to the db. So my first thought was to add a throbber and disable the button when its clicked. The throbber is spinning away but when the button is disabled it prevents the call to the server. So I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170798/disabling-a-button-doesnt-fire-click-event-on-server-side) but since I have a bunch of different buttons (Update, Add, ...) that there are a few different server side methods being called so I can't just post `__doPostBack($(button).attr('id'),'')`.
So i was thinking that I might need to do a ajax call but I wanted to see if there was any other ideas. 
 Here's my code: The `onClientClick` is actually being setup on the server side but this is basically whats being done.

**Repeater**:

```
<div style="position: relative; float: left;">
      <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Assign" OnClientClick="return fnAssignedButtonPressed(this);", OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
</div>
```

**Javscript**:

```
function fnAssignedButtonPressed(button) {
//validating inputs
var valid = true;

        if(valid)
        {
           $(button).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
           showWaitCursor(true);
           __doPostBack($(button).attr('id'),'');
        }
  return valid;
}
```

**Serverside**:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //save
 // This method doesn't call called when I disable the button!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this but I don't know how I feel about it..

```
function fnAssignedButtonPressed(button) 
{ 
//validating inputs 
var valid = true;
     if(valid)
     {
       showWaitCursor(true);
       //set a timeout and then disable the button, this prevents the user from click the button multiple times.
       // need the timeout bc when the button becomes disabled it prevents the onlick event from firing.
       setTimeout(function() {fnDisableButton(button)}, 1); 
    }
}

function fnDisableButton(button)
{
    $(button).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax could definitely be a good option depending on your scenario. Otherwise, you could show a please wait modal using jquery's UI dialog such as:

```
$('<div class="dialog" title="Please Wait">Please wait while your request is processing</div>').dialog({
    modal: true,
    width: 350,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
    },
});
```

Once the server returns, the modal should automatically disappear, and the modal option of the UI dialog grays out the screen so the user cannot click on anything.